# how to regroup, calculate the mean and generate new dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I am a freshman in R.
Recently I am working on a small project.
I have a dataset look like this: (Sorry for confidential purpose I cannot copy the real data)
Because in some counties, the chemicals have been measured multiple times.

```
id county chemicalA chemicalB chemicalC
1    a       0.1        NA      NA
1    a       0.3        NA      NA
1    a       0.2        NA      NA
1    a       0.2        NA      NA
2    b       0.4        0.2     NA
2    b       0.1        NA     NA
3    c       0.05       NA      0.8
4    d       NA         NA      0.4
4    d       0.2        NA      0.5
4    d       0.3        NA      0.6
```

Now I want to calculate the mean value of chemicals by county and generate a ideal data frame like this:

```
id county  meanA   meanB   meanC
 1    a     0.2     NA      NA
 2    b     0.25    0.2     NA
 3    c     0.05    NA      0.8
 4    d     0.25    NA      0.5
```

I Googled and I have tried functions like `tapply`, `group_by`, but they are not ideal.
For example, `tapply` can only generate a vector but I want a matrix with the id so that I can merge them all to generate the ideal data frame. I also tried to set up the data frame by `data.frame` first and fill it with the calculation but I cannot merge it by id.
Is there any other methods that can help me to generate my ideal data frame? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `summarise_at` after doing the grouping by 'id', 'county'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id, county) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

If a particular column for a group combination have only `NA`, this will return `NaN` as we use `na.rm = TRUE`.  To prevent that, either we can have a `if/else` condition

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(id, county) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ if(all(is.na(.)))
        NA_real_ else mean(., na.rm = TRUE))
```

or another option is `mean_` from `hablar`

```
library(hablar)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id, county) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), mean_)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   id [4]
#     id county chemicalA chemicalB chemicalC
#  <int> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1 a           0.2       NA        NA  
#2     2 b           0.25       0.2      NA  
#3     3 c           0.05      NA         0.8
#4     4 d           0.25      NA         0.5
```

Or if there are many other variables, we can apply on numeric columns with `summarise_if`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(id, county) %>%
   summarise_if(is.numeric, mean_)
```

Or for specific variables, either specify the column names or if there is any pattern in column name, i.e. here the column names starts with 'chemical'

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(id, county) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(starts_with('chemical')), mean_)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    county = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d"
    ), chemicalA = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.05, NA, 
    0.2, 0.3), chemicalB = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), chemicalC = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.8, 0.4, 
    0.5, 0.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: @Christina In that case, change `summarise_at` to `summarise_if(is.numericm mean, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @Christina or you can specify the variable names to do the computation i.e. `summarise_at(vars(starts_with('chemical')), `

Comment: Thanks! I accidentally deleted the previous comment. I also find another way to remove the irrelevant variables by using `summarise_at(vars(c("variable names","variable names")), mean, na.rm = TRUE)`. I think `starts_with` is also good for those variables with a series of similar naming.

Answer (score 0):

Using the builtin iris data as an example, data.table allows grouping through `by`

```
library(data.table)
dtIris <- data.table(iris)
dtIris[, .(
  meanPL = mean(Petal.Length,  na.rm = TRUE), 
  meanPW = mean(Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE)
), by = Species]
```

Or even better, using `.SD` too which will take mean for each column (not in `by`) or those passed to `.SDcols = ...`

```
dtIris[, 
  lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), 
  by = Species]
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, using `aggregate` :

```
aggregate(.~id+county, df, mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)

#  id county chemicalA chemicalB chemicalC
#1  1      a      0.20       NaN       NaN
#2  2      b      0.25       0.2       NaN
#3  3      c      0.05       NaN       0.8
#4  4      d      0.25       NaN       0.5
```

It returns `NaN` when there are no rows to aggregate, you can change it to `NA` if needed.